# How to list similar column names with select statement?

Tags: netezza

My table has several columns that have similar names, such as year_1, year_2, year_3, etc. Is there an easy way to list them all without typing all of them? I cannot use select *, because I don't want the other columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use dynamic nzplsql in a stored procedure. Stored procedures don't easily return tables, though, but you can have it easily output a select statement that builds from `_v_relation_column` via a cursor. Capture that in bash and feed it to `nzsql` to select from a table. Either that or you can just return a reftable.

```
/* Stored procedure header. */
declare sql varchar;
declare col record;
begin_proc
  sql := 'select ';
  for col in select * from _v_relation_column where name = 'TABLE_NAME' loop
    if col.attname like 'year%'
      sql := sql || attname || ',';
    end if;
  sql := substring(sql,1,length(sql)-1); --To strip the last comma. Could probably be more elegant.
  sql := sql || ' from table_name;';
  raise notice '%',sql;
end_proc;
/* Stored procedure footer. */
```